# Is it possible to reduce or change the font of the items of the UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, fonts, uipickerview, reduce

Is it possible to reduce or change the font of the items of the UIPickerView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` method in picker's delegate instead of `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`. You'll be able to create UILabel object there and setup all necessary properties for it.